What is the probability for a random walk starting from 25 hitting 125 twice before reaching origin?
Suppose i.i.d. random variable $X_i$ takes the value $\{-1, 1\}$ equiprobably and let $S_n = 25 + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
How can I calculate the probability that $S_n$ hits $125$ twice before hit $0$?
Following this post, we can derive the probability that $S_n$ hits $125$ before $0$. But I got stuck when I tried to decompose the event $\{\text{hitting 125 twice before 0}\}$ to make the previous post applicable.

You have the probability of hitting it once. Now what’s the probability of hitting it a second time, once you’re there? There’s a symmetry to exploit here.

@Malady Do you mean the probability that $S_n$ hits $125$ again before $0$ given that $S_n$ has arrived at $125$?

Let $A$ be the event that the walk started at $25$ hits $125$ twice before it hits $0$.
Notice that $A$ can be interpreted as the event that the walk hits $125$ before it hits $0$ and then, the walk restarted at the hitting time of $125$ hits $125$ again before it reaches $0$.
Let $T_{a}$ denote the hitting time of $a$ and we have $T=\min(T_{0} ,T_{125})$   is also a stopping time.
And let $B=\{(S_{T+n})_{n\geq 0}\,\text{hits 125 before}\, 0\}$
$P(A)=P(T=T_{125},B)=P(B|T=T_{125})\cdot P(T=T_{125})$
Note that by the strong Markov property, we have that $(S_{T+n}-S_{T})_{n\geq 0}$ is an independent simple symmetric random walk independent of $T$ and $(S_{n})_{n\leq T}$.
So, under the condition $T=T_{125}$, $P(B|T=T_{125})$ equals the probability of a simple symmetric random walk started at $0$ to hit $0$ before it hits the level $(-125)$.
Now, here's a fact about symmetric random walks,
Given integers $a,b>0$, we have $P(T_{-a}<T_{b})=\frac{b}{a+b}$ and $P(T_{b}<T_{-a})=\frac{a}{a+b}$.
So $P(T=T_{125})=\frac{25}{125}$ (i.e. the probability starting at $25$ and hitting $125$ before $0$ is equal to the probability of starting at $0$ and hitting $100$ before hitting $-25$.)
Now when we are restarting the walk at $T=T_{125}$, we can condition on the first step.
If we move up (we do so with probability $\frac{1}{2}$), then we are at the level $126$ and then as the random walk is recurrent, it must hit $0$ again and to do so, it must pass through the level $125$.
If we move down (we do so with probability $\frac{1}{2}$), then we are at the level $124$ and then the probability of the restarted walk at the level $124$ to hit $125$ before it hits $0$, is equal to the probability of a simple symmetric random walk started at $0$ to hit $1$ before it hits $-124$. By the formula above, this equals $\frac{124}{125}$.
So combining we have $$P(A)=\bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{124}{125}\bigg)\cdot\frac{25}{125}$$
